# How to use datatable in R for filter by rows and columns?

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data frame and I use the `DT` package. I want to filter by column and row. For simplicity, I have this data frame

```
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars)
```

I want to filter the columns by the hp and by car for example. This implies filtering by row and column. In reality, my data frame has rows of names of the players and columns with the same names of the player and each cell has the probability of one player wins over the other. That's why I want a faster way to filter by row and column as there are so many players.
I tried to read the documentation but there is no example of what I want. By reading I got this code

```
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars, selection = 'multiple' target = list(rows = 1, cols = 2)))
```

The output is the same. I also read that shiny app might do the work.

To summarize I want to be able to filter by row and column of a interative dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you turned the row.names into a column of it's own, you'd be back to filtering on only columns, right?

If so, you could try this:

```r
library(DT)
library(tibble)

datatable(
    rownames_to_column(mtcars,"Car"),
    filter="top"
)
```

[image]

Comment: This code also filters only by rows. What I want is to filter by rows and columns. For example, be able to pick the value of hp for Datsun 710

Comment: so remove all other columns than hp for example? or what do you mean by "pick"?

Comment: Yes! Exactly like that. This is just an example, in reality, these are the player's name and I have 110 players. So I have a data frame with 110 columns and 110 rows, that's why I want to remove all columns except the one I choose. For example, If I want to see the wt and Merc 280 just type those words and I will keep only with the row of Merc 280 and the wt column.